# How to perform click event on View Pager in android

Tags: android, onclick, android-viewpager

I need to show an image in full screen, on clicking of View Pager in android.
    I have tried this.

```
view.myPager.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.e("VIEW PAGER", "VIEW PAGER");
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "ZOOM", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });*
```

Suggestion appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: show something which you have tried .

Comment: what u have done..........

Comment: view.myPager.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     Log.e("VIEW PAGER", "VIEW PAGER");
     Toast.makeText(activity, "ZOOM", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
   });

Answer (score 2):

Set the listener on the image inside instantiateItem():

```
        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
            final LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater(); 
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null);
            final ImageView image = (ImageView)layout.findViewById(R.id.image_display);
            final int cPos = position;
            image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    ImageView i = (ImageView)v;
                    if(cPos == 0)
                    {
                        //...
                    }
                    //...

                }
            });

            return layout;
        }
```

Alternatively, you could use the `ImageView.setTag()` method to include data about what Activity to launch. e.g.

```
if(position == 0) image.setTag("com.blah.android.SomeActivity");
if(position == 1) image.setTag("com.blah.android.AnotherActivity");
//...
```

And the inside the onClick() above have this instead:

```
ImageView i = (ImageView)v;
String activityClassName = (String)i.getTag();   // Get the info we stored in the tag.
MyActivity.this.startActivity((new Intent()).setClassName(MyActivity.this, activityClassName));
```

Note that here you don't actually need the cast to ImageView, since `getTag()` is a method of `View`. You also don't need a separate OnClickListener for each ImageView. You could just create a single instance of an OnClickListener that grabs the tag data as above, and launches the appropriate activity. Set this OnClickListener on every ImageView inside `instantiateItem()`.

P.S. I strongly recommend, if you are downloading images, that you look at some of the image downloaders that have been written for Android. e.g.
https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Answer (score 1):

You cannot click on a `ViewPager`, as a `ViewPager` *manages* a UI, but does not have its own UI.

You will need to add appropriate listeners (e.g., `OnClickListener`) to widgets *inside* pages in the `ViewPager`, just as you would for an app that did not have a `ViewPager`.